# using f2py compiled functions into numba with 'nopython' mode

Tags: python, fortran, numba, f2py

I'm trying to use a f2py compiled function into a python function decorated with the @njit decorator from numba. The signature of the function wrapped by f2py is:

```
stp,f,g,task = xxx(stp,f,g,ftol,gtol,xtol,task,stpmin,stpmax,isave,dsave)

Wrapper for ``xxx``.

Parameters
----------
stp : input float
f : input float
g : input float
ftol : input float
gtol : input float
xtol : input float
task : input string(len=60)
stpmin : input float
stpmax : input float
isave : in/output rank-1 array('i') with bounds (2)
dsave : in/output rank-1 array('d') with bounds (13)

Returns
-------
stp : float
f : float
g : float
task : string(len=60)
```

and the signature file includes:

```
        subroutine xxx(stp,f,g,ftol,gtol,xtol,task,stpmin,stpmax,isave,dsave)
            double precision, intent(in,out) :: stp
            double precision, intent(in,out) :: f
            double precision, intent(in,out) :: g
            double precision, intent(in) :: ftol
            double precision, intent(in) :: gtol
            double precision, intent(in) :: xtol
            character*60, intent(in, out) :: task
            double precision, intent(in) :: stpmin
            double precision, intent(in) :: stpmax
            integer dimension(2), intent(inout) :: isave
            double precision dimension(13), intent(inout) :: dsave
        end subroutine xxx
```

Because in 'nopython' mode numba must be aware of the signature of the external function, my current approach is to directly load the xxx.so filed generated by f2py with ctypes, instead of the standard 'import' approach. Then, I register the input and output arguments of the function with ctypes in the following way:

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('xxx.so')
lib.dcsrch_.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double,
                        ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double,
                        ctypes.c_char_p(???), ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double,
                        np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.intc, ndim=1, shape=2), 
                        np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=1, shape=13)]
lib.dcsrch_.restype = ctypes.py_object(???).
```

Here, the (???) indicates that I am particularly uncertain of the signature. When I try to use the function I always get seg. fault errors. At the same time, when importing the function in the standard way, i.e. from xxx import xxx, everything run smoothly.

I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could find the answers in the argument specification in the `__doc__` by doing something like

```
from xxx import xxx
print(xxx.__doc__)
# or
print(xxx.function_name.__doc__)
```